# Can't send car loyalty card in request. I'm getting two warnings

Tags: sabre

I'm trying to send a book request with car loyalty card.
I've added CustLoyalty to PD.PassengerDetailsRQ -> TravelItineraryAddInfoRQ->PD.CustomerInfo -> CustLoyalty with MembershipID=number of card loyalty of user,                    ProgramID=program code.I do not send  NameNumber, SegmentNumber, TravelingCarrierCode.
However I'm getting 2 warnings in response

```
<soap-env:Body>
    <PassengerDetailsRS xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/pd/v3_4">
      <ApplicationResults xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/STL_Payload/v02_01" xmlns:ns2="http://services.sabre.com/essm/diagnostic/v1" xmlns:ns3="http://services.sabre.com/essm/core/v1" xmlns:ns4="http://services.sabre.com/STL_Payload/v02_02" xmlns:ns5="http://opentravel.org/common/v02" xmlns:ns6="http://opentravel.org/common/message/v02" xmlns:ns7="http://services.sabre.com/sp/ssp/v1" xmlns:ns8="http://services.sabre.com/STL_Header/v02_02" xmlns:ns9="http://services.sabre.com/STL_Header/v120" xmlns:ns10="http://services.sabre.com/essm/session/v1" xmlns:ns11="http://services.sabre.com/STL_Header/v02_01" xmlns:ns12="http://webservices.sabre.com/servicesplatform/eiapi/1.0.0" xmlns:ns13="http://www.OpenTravel.org/ns/OTA2/AppInfo_v01_00" xmlns:ns14="http://services.sabre.com/sp/preferences/v1" xmlns:ns15="http://services.sabre.com/STL/v01" xmlns:ns16="http://services.sabre.com/ssse/trace/v01" status="Complete">
        <Success timeStamp="2022-10-21T01:43:18.739-05:00"/>
        <Warning timeStamp="2022-10-21T01:43:14.930-05:00" type="BusinessLogic">
          <SystemSpecificResults>
            <Message code="WARN.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE">TravelItineraryAddInfoLLSRQ: .UNABLE TO ACCEPT FQTV NUMBERS FOR ZD - CALL DIRECT</Message>
          </SystemSpecificResults>
        </Warning>
        <Warning timeStamp="2022-10-21T01:43:18.738-05:00" type="BusinessLogic">
          <SystemSpecificResults>
            <Message code="WARN.SP.PROVIDER_WARNING">Missing expected CustLoyalty information</Message>
          </SystemSpecificResults>
        </Warning>
```

Could you, please, help me, how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That element in the PassengerDetailsRQ is for airline membership numbers.  There is no specific field in a Sabre PNR for a car membership number.  The car membership numbers needs to be included in the car sell request.

Comment: thank you, I stopped to put CustLoyalty in PassengerDetailsRQ.
And leave only in OTA_VehResLLSRQ in the car sell request. However, I got another warning 
{
'_value_1': 'FREQUENT TRAVELER UNAVAILABLE FOR THIS RENTAL',
'code': None
},
What does it mean, that my membership in the car loyalty program is not suitable for this rent?
How I can define if is it suitable or not?